# How to Transfer a call over H323 Trunk in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, transfer, phone-call

I have an incoming call from Ericsson PBX to Asterisk through H323 trunk and I want to transfer this call back to Ericsson and then shutdown Asterisk. Transfer function does not work over H323 and if I use Dial when I shutdown Asterisk call will be disconnected.
Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

h323 trunk in asterisk NOT support transfer.

That was not implemented and seam will be never implemented, becuase h323 is not widly used nowdays